# How can I prevent the Node IIFE function from running via an injection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, code-injection

My scenario is that I am exploring code injection, so the var / let is left off on purpose in the IIFE function.

What is the best way to prevent IIFE from running? If I try this code in my Node REPL, the hammerhead variable lands on the global scope. I am trying to figure out how I can prevent code injection, like this.  Is there a way to convert all the Arguments to a string before the IFFE is run?

```
function keepItLocal(input) {
  console.log(input);
  return input;
}
keepItLocal('test', (function IIFE() {
  hammerhead = 'on the global scope';
  console.log(hammerhead);
  return 1
}()));
```

node REPL > hammerhead

prints

'on the global scope'

I thought that perhaps I could turn the Arguments into a String, but it seems JavaScript evaluates the IIFE first.

```
function keepItLocal(input) {
  arguments = Array(...arguments.toString());
  console.log(arguments);
  console.log(input);
  return input;
}
keepItLocal('test', (function IIFE() {
  hammerhead = 'on the global scope';
  console.log(hammerhead);
  return 1
}()));
```

Comment: `What is the best way to prevent IFFE from running?` you can't ... it's an IIFE and II stands for Immediately Invoked - it's in the definition ... it's invoked immediately

Comment: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/c0pr7yux/) what you want your code to do?

Comment: I'd like to only use the input argument and drop everything else.

Comment: then don't pass in  the IIFE :p OK, but there's no way to stop IIFE from being II

Comment: thanks, yes. haha.  I'm exploring code injection. So lets say I don't have control over what is passed into the function. Would I be able to restrict what is passed in? Proxy perhaps?

Comment: [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Converting_mistakes_into_errors) may help - this won't prevent the IIFE from being invoked, but it should error out because of a global variable declaration

Comment: thank @ThomasAltmann. I don't seem to be able to have strict mode work in node and throw an error with an IIFE

Comment: @Hillsie you prevent code injection by not running untrusted code, it's that simple. If you cannot control that, you've already lost.

Comment: Notice that this IIFE argument is not any different from just running `hammerhead = 'on the global scope'; console.log(hammerhead); keepItLocal('test', 1);`. There's nothing that your `keepItLocal` function can do about its caller.

Comment: Thanks @Bergin , thanks all. I can't find anyway to capture the IIFE before it's invoked.